# Criar o meu próprio servidor de mensagens Push

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification

Para usar PN (Push Notification) eu normalmente faço uso de servidores em nuvens tais como Firebase, Azure, etc.

Agora peguei um serviço para fazer e meu cliente exige que tenhamos o nosso próprio servidor.

Vi esse [link no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329403/android-push-notification-without-using-gcm), mas se alguém tem algo mais simples e quiser compartilhar, agradeço. Apenas Android.

Comment: Pnet te recomendo a fazer o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como funciona a comunidade, primeiramente tente fazer algo, depois faça a pergunta expondo sua dúvida e ou problema.

Comment: Olá pnet, não tem como te explicar do início ao fim como transofrmar o domínio em um pwa, mas existe toda a documentação disponível no google, primeiro você deve registrar um service worker no domínio em seguida além de poder adicionar o ico no homescreen do android você pode implementar o serviço de push notifications. Siga essa documentação é bem extensa mas depois que entende fica bem facíl de montar : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/?hl=pt-br . Abraços qualquer dúvida só postar.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão, não li toda a documentação ainda, mas sei que não existe algo simples para o que eu quero. Por isso, transforme seu comentário em resposta que eu marco para não ficar um post aberto. Sei que a solução é algo como vc comentou, inclusive no site do Xamarin alguém me respondeu muito próximo do que você me disse.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão, como disse não li toda a documentação ainda, estou fazendo isso, mas me responda o seguinte. Esse link passado eu tenho como fazer um servidor de mensagens? O que eu quero é ter uma forma de enviar PN para todos os App's desenvolvidos pela empresa. E não apenas em minha máquina, até porque tenho apenas 2 meses para desenvolver tudo isso. O Servidor ficará na empresa e eu parto para outros projetos.

Comment: Eu posso abrir uma resposta resumida com uma cópia de sw.js e manifesto de um dos meus domínios, bastaria você copiar e instalar no domínio do seu cliente, alterando apenas algumas coisas. Esse é o primeiro passo para ter push notifications transformar o domínio em um progressive web app.  O domínio em questão estra sobre https ?

Comment: Posso ver sim. Se puder enviar te agradeço, @RafaelSalomão

Comment: Verifica se o cliente usa https? Vou formular uma resposta !

Comment: Sim, usa. Tudo porque não querem usar cloud. Seria bem mais fácil, rs. É a minha primeira vez usando um servidor local para PN.

Comment: Vou adicionando abaixo e salvando apenas para não perder o que escrevi.

Comment: @pnet você colocou **"Apenas Android"** em sua pergunta... O que seria isto? Uma aplicação (app) nativa? Uma aplicação hibrida? O navegador nativo do Android? Aplicativos de navegador(es) disponíveis em Android?

Comment: @LauroMoraes, é apenas para Android. Uso forms mas é para android apenas. A PN será apenas em dispositivos Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Implementando Progressive Web APP em seu domínio.**

Requisítos Mínimos:

1. O domínio deve estar sobre https (encriptação ssl).
2. O domínio deve possuir um arquivo de manifesto válido.
3. O domínio deve passar em uma auditoria de browser que irei descrever abaixo.

Bom, para se ter o **web push notifications** é necessário antes transformar o seu domínio em um progressive web app. Além do push notifications varias outras vantagens são fornecidas, como cache estático direto do navegador o que permite navegar sobre o domínio com o dispositivo offline, a adição de um ícone de atalho diretamente inserido no homescreen do usuário e a navegação em forma de aplicativo móvel sem a dependência de um navegador.

> Registrando um arquivo de manifesto:

Na raiz de seu domínio você deve incluir um arquivo json vamos chama-lo de manifesto.json neste exemplo:

```
{
  "short_name"       : "teste",
  "name"             : "meudominio.com",
  "display"          : "standalone",
  "background_color" : "#131b26",
  "theme_color"      : "#131b26",
  "icons"            : [{  "src"  : "tema/BlueRED/images/48x48.png",
                           "type" : "image/png",
                           "sizes": "48x48"
                        },
                        {  "src"  : "tema/BlueRED/images/96x96.png",
                           "type" : "image/png",
                            "sizes": "96x96"
                        },
                        {  "src"  : "tema/BlueRED/images/192x192.png",
                           "type" : "image/png",
                           "sizes": "192x192"
                        },
                        {  "src"  : "tema/BlueRED/images/256x256.png",
                           "type" : "image/png",
                            "sizes": "256x256"
                        },
                        {  "src"  : "tema/BlueRED/images/512x512.png",
                           "type" : "image/png",
                           "sizes": "512x512"
                        }],
  "start_url": "/ utm_source=homescreen&amp;utm_medium=pwa&amp;utm_campaign=pwa"
}
```

Você também ira precisar de uma imagem em grande formato (512x512), para gerar imagens menores como nos tamanhos descritos no nosso manifesto.json acima. Essas imagens são utilizadas pelo android para adicionar ícone ao homescreen do usuário dependendo do tamanho do display. Existem ferramentas que dimensionam a imagem para você bastando possuir uma imagem no formato acima mensionado para não perder a resolução. Também o web aplicativo cria o manifesto sozinho para você, bastando preencher o formulário. Utilize essa ferramenta para criar seu manifesto.json e as imagens já dimensionadas. ([Generator Manifesto Json](https://app-manifest.firebaseapp.com/))

Após gerar seu arquivo de manifesto deve indicar no head do domínio que ele existe adicionando a seguinte meta em todas as páginas.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifesto.json" />
```

> Criando um arquivo com as rotinas de seu service worker.

Definição by Google :

**Um service worker é um script que seu navegador executa em segundo
plano, separado da página da Web, possibilitando recursos que não
precisam de uma página da Web ou de interação do usuário. Atualmente,
os service workers já incluem recursos como notificações push e
sincronização em segundo plano.**

Registrando um arquivo sw.js. (Nosso Service Worker)

Essa minha solução é voltada a cache estático de todos os recursos do domínio, o que permite uma navegação mesmo que offline.

```
var CACHE_VERSION = 26;  
/* Esse é o número de versão do cache muito importante. Se mudar a versão 
força todos os navegadores que possuem nosso service worker registrado, a 
excluírem suas copias e solicitarem ao servidor uma nova copia dos arquivos 
cacheados. */
var CURRENT_CACHES = {
    prefetch: 'prefetch-cache-v' + CACHE_VERSION
};

self.addEventListener('install', function(event){
   /* Dentro dessa lista é adicionado todos os arquivos estáticos do domínio 
   um por um, antes que o usuário solicite a pagina todo esse conteúdo é 
   baixado para o navegador utilizando uma cabeça em background do 
   navegador. Você pode cachear páginas,imagens,css entre outras 
   coisas  que nem foram abertas ainda. 
   O resultado é um site absurdamente rápido, e  com o tempo de 
   permanência exageradamente alto. Alguns de meus domínio possuem 12 
   minutos ou mais de duração média da visita, assim como a taxa de rejeição 
   despencou*/ 
   var urlsToPrefetch = [ '/tema/BlueRED/images/pix.gif',
                           '/js/sprite.js',
                           '/tema/BlueRED/images/640X400.jpg' ];
    console.log('Handling install event. Resources to prefetch:', urlsToPrefetch);

    self.skipWaiting();

    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.prefetch).then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll(urlsToPrefetch);
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event){
/*Se este nome de cache não estiver presente na matriz de nomes de cache 
"esperados", então exclua-o.*/
    var expectedCacheNames = Object.keys(CURRENT_CACHES).map(function(key) {
        return CURRENT_CACHES[key];
    });

    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames){
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
                    if (expectedCacheNames.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
                        console.log('Deleting out of date cache:', cacheName);
                        return caches.delete(cacheName);
                    }
                })
            );
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event){
    console.log(event.request);
    if(!event.request.headers.get('range')){
        event.respondWith(
            /* caches.match  irá procurar um entrada no cache de browser 
            para a requisição feita para o arquivo estático interceptando 
            qualquer requisição até seu servidor, caso encontre ele responde 
            ao cliente localmente do navegador.*/               
            caches.match(event.request).then(function(response){
                if (response) {
                    /* Se encontrou uma resposta válida para o arquivo 
                    solicitado responde localmente com o cache */
                    console.log('Found response in cache:', response);
                    return response;
                }
                /* Caso não encontre o arquivo cacheado efetua uma 
                requisição até o servidor para solicitar o arquivo */
                console.log('No response found in cache. About to fetch from network...');
                // event.request will always have the proper mode set ('cors, 'no-cors', etc.) so we don't
                // have to hardcode 'no-cors' like we do when fetch()ing in the install handler.
                return fetch(event.request).then(function(response){
                    console.log('Response from network is:', response);
                    caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.prefetch).then(function(cache){
                      if(response.type != 'opaque' && response.type != 'cors' && response.url != 'https://www.meudominio.com/sw.js'){
                        /* Se a requisição tiver sido efetuada essa rotina 
                       adiciona o arquivo ao cache, mas antes faz o devido 
                       tratamento para requisições opacas e o propio arquivo 
                       sw.js não ser cacheado.*/
                       console.log("cache adicionado:"+response.url);
                       cache.add(response.url);
                      }
                    });
                    return response;
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.error('Fetching failed:', error);
                    throw error;
                });
            })
        );
    }
});
```

Por fim, deve existir uma rotina javascript contida em todas as páginas de seu domínio, para que no primeiro acesso do usuário ao domínio efetue o registro de nosso service worker, caso ele não tenha sido registrado nesse navegador ainda.

Nesse caso podemos implementar da forma abaixo:

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) 
     {
       // Registration was successful
       console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', 
       registration.scope);
     }).catch(function(err) {
          // registration failed :(
         console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
     });
    });
}

function waitUntilInstalled(registration){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       if (registration.installing) {
           // If the current registration represents the "installing" service worker, then wait
           // until the installation step (during which the resources are pre-fetched) completes
           // to display the file list.
          registration.installing.addEventListener('statechange', function(e) {
           if (e.target.state === 'installed'){
              resolve();
           }else if (e.target.state === 'redundant'){
              reject();
           }
       });
     }else{
          /* Otherwise, if this isn't the "installing" service worker, then 
          installation must have been */
          /* completed during a previous visit to this page, and the resources are already pre-fetched.*/
          // So we can show the list of files right away.
          resolve();
     }
  });
}

if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js',{
        scope: '/'
    }).then(waitUntilInstalled)
      //.then(showFilesList)
     .catch(function(error) {
       // Something went wrong during registration. The service-worker.js file
       // might be unavailable or contain a syntax error.
       document.querySelector('#status').textContent = error;
     });
 }else{
      // The current browser doesn't support service workers.
      var aElement         = document.createElement('a');
      aElement.href        = 'http://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq';
      aElement.textContent = 'Service workers are not supported in the current browser.';
      document.querySelector('#status').appendChild(aElement);
 }
```

Essa rotina é executada antes da abertura do domínio, é responsável por validar e registrar o service worker para o domínio. Após tudo isso feito, deve se abrir o console no google chrome e efetuar a validação de todos os passos acima, utilizando a ferramenta na guia **audits** do navegador. Se houver qualquer problema com a implementação o próprio debug do navegador ira lhe fornecer a página de documentação com a explicação dos erros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após o PWA implementado, você pode iniciar a implementação do web push notifications, essa documentação lhe será útil [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/?hl=pt-br). Espero que o humilde post ajude!

Comment: Qualquer dúvida adicional add skype salomao4598. Abraços!

Comment: Cara, estou tentando implementar isso. Vou tentar primeiro em meu site, para isso estou transferindo para a CloudFlare, para mudar de HTTP para HTTPS. Após receber o certificado, vou testar seu código, mas olhando o arquivo **manifesto.json** para que serve aquelas imagens dentro do json?

Comment: Alterei a resposta

Comment: Tenho dúvida na URL. Exemplo antes da barra seria a minha url padrão, certo? E vejo que você colocou vários após a barra. Oque isso significa

Answer (score 4):

> Prefácio¹:

Primeiramente deve-se entender que que os serviços de **Push Notification** no âmbito móvel (mobile) são implementados pelo fabricante de software (normalmente integrado via SO).

A base de seu funcionamento é o **"Serviço de Notificação de Envio do Sistema Operacional"** (OSPNS). Cada sistema operacional móvel (SO), incluindo iOS, Android, Firefox OS, Windows, BlackBerry entre outros possuem seu próprio serviço. Navegadores utilizam o **"endpoint"** destes serviços (seus próprios) para dar suporte a `API` `Web Push` como descrito mais adiante.

A metodologia de sua implementação segue o conceito **[Pub/Sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)** (subscrição/publicação) onde, o dispositivo se inscreve em um serviço (servidor) informando um **id** exclusivo do aplicativo e então esta apito a receber uma publicação (notificação). Para tal o dispositivo "observa" constantemente o serviço afim de verificar se há (existe) uma nova publicação (notificação) a ser entregue.

Como mencionado anteriormente estes serviços (servidores) estão "embarcados" pelo fabricante de software e o método bem como a frequência de verificação são definidas pelos fabricantes.

A exemplo disto podemos listar por exemplo:

- Apple APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) (iOS/Mac OS X)
- Google GCM/FCM (Google Cloud Messaging/Firebase Cloud Messaging) (Android)
- Mozila Autopush (Mozilla Push server and Push Endpoint) (Firefox/Firefox OS)
- Windows WNS (Windows Push Notification Services) (UWP)
- Microsoft MPNS (Microsoft Push Notification Service) (Windows Phone 8)
- Amazon ADM (Amazon Device Messaging) (by [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sns/))
- Baidu Cloud Push (Baidu Cloud Push SDK)
- Tizen SPPCD² (Samsung Push Service) (Tizen OS)

> NOTAS:
>
> - a exemplo da lista acima APNS pode ser usada tanto no dispositivo (iOS/Mac OS X) quando em um watchOS 3 ou posterior... o sistema decide qual dispositivo recebera a notificação. Veja mais detalhes na [documentação oficial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html).
> - Autopush é utilizado no sistema móvel da Mozila assim como para atender a especificação [Web Push](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-webpush-protocol/) em aplicações web usando Firefox. Veja mais detalhes na [documentação oficial](https://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
> - Windows WNS é utilizado em UWP (Universal Windows Platform) que integra os serviços conectados da décima (10) versão deste SO.

Outros SO's móveis derivados (por exemplo do Android) podem usar os serviços de sua fonte base ou providenciarem seu próprio serviço.

---

> Implementar um serviço próprio:

No momento desta publicação (27/12/2017) desconheço a possibilidade de implementar um serviço próprio para utilização nativa de notificações push em um dispositivo vindas de uma origem remota.

O uso das funções nativas para push requer o registro em um serviço (até então proprietário), não é possível dispará-las localmente (no dispositivo) sem estarem previamente registradas (de uma origem registrada).

> Alternativas:

Existem muitas alternativas (servidores de aplicativos push), algumas gratuitas outras pagas que em suma irão utilizar alguns dos serviços acima citados.

Estas ferramentas (servidores de aplicativos push) por sua vez utilizam plugins ou ferramentas integradas ao `SDK` do sistema em questão para estender classes e funcionalidades nativas referentes aos serviços de **"push"** afim de manusear as requisições (diga-se REST) destes serviços.

O grande diferencial se dá no fato destas ferramentas propiciarem algum grau de automação (por exemplo para marketing) bem como a possibilidade de ferramentas de gestão e analise coisa que por padrão é restrito aos fabricantes de software más, como a mensagem é encriptada estes serviços (proprietários) funcionam como um **gatekeeper** baseado no `TTL` (time-to-live) e na prioridade da mensagem.

Estas ferramentas também possibilitam que você possa utilizar de um acesso remoto (por exemplo um servidor de uma aplicação web ou via linha de comando) para lançar novas notificações ou em alguns casos obter métricas (dados de analise de uso) via `API`.

Seguindo o raciocínio destas "ferramentas" sua aplicação poderia manter uma conexão com seu servidor e lançar uma notificação usando **"Insert [Android]"**... este método necessitaria obrigatoriamente de uma `API Key` do GCM e poderia ser usada tanto pelo GCM como FCM ou mesmo pelo plugin Cordova (no caso de um aplicativo Cordova).

**exemplo usando "Insert"** - (ver código comentado [gist](https://gist.github.com/subversivo58/d6b4b6ec9af77cff996c40d927a61113#file-android-notification-insert-js)):

```
/* Firebase instruções */
public class InsertFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {    
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {    
        if ( remoteMessage.getNotification() != null ) {    
            RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();    
            int iconResId = 0;
            final String drawableResourceName = notification.getIcon();
            if ( !TextUtils.isEmpty(drawableResourceName) ) {
                iconResId = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableResourceName, "drawable", getPackageName());
            }
            Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            final String soundFileName = notification.getSound();    
            if ( !TextUtils.isEmpty(soundFileName) && !soundFileName.equals("default") ) {
                sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + soundFileName);
            }    
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();    
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : remoteMessage.getData().entrySet()) {
                bundle.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }    
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Your App Name")
            .setContentText(notification.getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(iconResId == 0 ? getApplicationInfo().icon : iconResId)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setContentIntent(Insert.generatePendingIntentForPush(bundle));    
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);    
            nm.notify(0, builder.build());
        }
    }
}

/* GCM instruções */
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super("RegistrationIntentService");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            Insert.setPushId(token);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
} 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
startService(intent);

public class InsertInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}

public class InsertGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {    
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, final Bundle data) {    
        int iconResId = 0;
        final String drawableResourceName =  data.getBundle("notification").getString("icon");
        if ( !TextUtils.isEmpty(drawableResourceName) ) {
            iconResId = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableResourceName, "drawable", getPackageName());
        }    
        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        final String soundFileName = data.getBundle("notification").getString("sound");
        if ( !TextUtils.isEmpty(soundFileName) && !soundFileName.equals("default") ) {
            sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + soundFileName);
        }    
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Your App Name")
        .setContentText(data.getString("message"))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(iconResId == 0 ? getApplicationInfo().icon : iconResId)
        .setSound(sound)
        .setContentIntent(Insert.generatePendingIntentForPush(data));    
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}

/* Cordova (Push Notification plugin) instruções */

// Cordova command line:
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=<sender-id>
// Add the following code after "onDeviceReady" 
var push = PushNotification.init({
    "android": {
        "senderID": "<sender-id>"
    },
    "ios": {
        "alert": "true",
        "badge": "true",
        "sound": "true"
    },
    "windows": {}
 });
 push.on('registration', function(data) {
     window.plugins.Insert.setPushId(data.registrationId);
 });
 push.on('notification', function(data) {
     //...
 });
 push.on('error', function(e) {
     console.log(e.message);
 });
```

Fonte: [support.insert.io](https://support.insert.io/hc/en-us/articles/209724505-Send-push-notifications-via-Insert-Android-)

Se o intuito for simplesmente notificar o usuário sua aplicação (mobile) poderia se comunicar com um servidor remoto através do uso de `WebSockets` ou de alguma biblioteca como de terceiros e utilizar uma função nativa de notificação... **"más isto já não seria uma push notification"**!

**exemplo (Android)** - (ver código comentado [gist](https://gist.github.com/subversivo58/d6b4b6ec9af77cff996c40d927a61113#file-android-notification-example-js))

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
        0,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Fonte: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

A exemplo disto o Facebook Messenger utiliza no Android e no iOS seu próprio `gateway` usando **[MQTT](http://mqtt.org/)** para enviar e receber notificações.

Diga-se no iOS, uma vez que os aplicativos não podem executar serviços em segundo plano por muito tempo, eles usam **APNs** quando o aplicativo está fechado e **[MQTT](http://mqtt.org/)** quando aberto.

Fonte: [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/why_facebook_is_using_mqtt_on_mobile?lang=en).

Há também a possibilidade de criar um "servidor de aplicativos push"...

> Servidores de aplicativo push:

Existem uma gama consideravelmente boa (questão de opinião) de projetos de código fonte aberto que podem servir para criar seu próprio **serviço de aplicativos push** a seguinte listagem reflete alguns:

- **[rpush](https://github.com/rpush/rpush)**

  - escrito em: Ruby
  - suporte a: APNS, FCM, ADM, WPNS
  - licensa: MIT
- **[gorush](https://github.com/appleboy/gorush)**

  - escrito em: Go
  - suporta a: APNS, FCM
  - licensa: MIT
- **[pushd](https://github.com/rs/pushd)**

  - escrito em: CoffeeScript
  - suporte a: APNS, GCM, WNS, MPNS, HTTP (POST), EventSource
  - licensa: MIT
- **[uniqush-push](https://github.com/uniqush/uniqush-push)**

  - escrito em: Go
  - suporte a: APNS, GCM, ADM
  - licensa: Apache-2.0

Para o uso especifico em Android sua aplicação (configurada para Push) usando as credencias FCM seguiria o seguinte esquema:

[image: push]

---

> Relacionado: [Web Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/API_Push)

A `API` **Web Push** atualmente encontra-se no ciclo **WD** (rascunho) segundo o [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/), esta `API` foi projetada para trazer aos aplicativos da web a funcionalidade dos serviços **"Push Notification"** e segundo [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=push-api) na data atual (26/12/2017) é suportada nos seguintes navegadores móveis do sistema Android (além de navegadores desktop):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Opera Mobile (37)
- Chrome for Android (62)
- Firefox for Android (57)
- UC for Android (11.4)
- Samsung Internet (62)
- QQ Browser (1.2)

Para criar um **"servidor de aplicativos push"** que utilizam **Web Push** existem uma grande oferta de projetos Open Source dentre os quais eu indicaria o seguinte repositório que contem um acervo de fontes:

- **[web-push-libs](https://github.com/web-push-libs)** - este acervo contém fontes em:

  - C, PHP, JavaScript, Python, C# e Java (constantemente atualizados)

Contudo esta `API` tem suas "peculiaridades" como o uso (obrigatório) da `API` [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) bem como de permissões do usuário para usar as [notificações](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/notificacoes) do navegador.

Sua especificação exige que o servidor forneça uma chave `VAPID` (Voluntary Application Server Identification) conforme descrito na [RFC8292](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8292).

Para um breve entendimento tomo como referência o uso da biblioteca [web-push](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push) escrita em `JavaScript` para rodar em **[NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/)**... esta biblioteca segue o protocolo Web Push bem como a [RFC8030](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8030) para encriptar as mensagens desta `API` além de, conter um método para gerar chaves `VAPID` (útil porque economiza trabalho).

**exemplo (cronologia)**:

1- gerar um par de chaves `VAPID` de seu servidor

2- criar rotas de "subscrição/remover subscrição" (usando rotas **[Express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html)**)

3- adicionar um **Service Worker**

4- requisitar ao usuário o uso de [notificações](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/notificacoes) (e ter aprovação)

5- testar (registrar-se/remover registro)

**exemplo código (gerar chaves VAPID)** - (ver código comentado [gist](https://gist.github.com/subversivo58/d6b4b6ec9af77cff996c40d927a61113#file-vapid-generator-js)):

```
const webpush = require('web-push')
const vapidKeys = webpush.generateVAPIDKeys()
console.log({
    pub: vapidKeys.publicKey,
    pri: vapidKeys.privateKey
})
```

Ambas as chaves (publico/privada) são utilizadas no servidor já a chave publica é utilizada no front-end no **Service Worker** que veremos mais a frente.

**exemplo código (criando rotas)** - (ver código comentado [gist](https://gist.github.com/subversivo58/d6b4b6ec9af77cff996c40d927a61113#file-route-js)):

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
webpush.setVapidDetails(
    'mailto:example@yourdomain.org',
    process.env.PUSH_PUB,
    process.env.PUSH_PRI
)
router.post('push/subscribe', (req, res, next) => {
    const subscription = {
        endpoint: req.body.endpoint,
        keys: {
            p256dh: req.body.keys.p256dh,
            auth: req.body.keys.auth
        }
    }
    let pushId = subscription.keys.p256dh.replace(/-/g,'').replace(/=/g,'')
    let payload = JSON.stringify({
        title: 'Um titulo legal',
        body: 'Alguma coisa aqui...',
        icon: 'imagem.png'
    })
    let options = {
        TTL: 60
    }
    webpush.sendNotification(subscription, payload, options).then(response => {
        //...
    }).catch(e => {
        //...
    })
})

router.post('/push/unsubscribe', (req, res, next) => {
    let pushId = req.body.keys.p256dh.replace(/-/g,'').replace(/=/g,'')
    //...
})
```

Não existe um padrão de respostas para o front-end isto fica a critério do desenvolvedor... boas dicas seriam:

- para inscrição os status:

  - 500 para um erro "generalizado" (não descrito)
  - 406 caso os requisitos não sejam aceitos (Not Acceptable)
  - 201 para um registro realizado com sucesso (Created)
- para remover inscrição os status:

  - 500 para um erro "generalizado" (não descrito)
  - 404 caso não encontre (não haja) uma chave registrada (Not Found)
  - 406 caso os requisitos não sejam aceitos (Not Acceptable)
  - 200 para uma remoção realizada com sucesso (OK)

Caso o sistema seja utilizado somente para usuários registrados na aplicação o status `403` (Forbidden) para tentativas de acesso por usuários não logados em sessão.

**exemplo Service Worker (sw.js)** - (ver código comentado [gist](https://gist.github.com/subversivo58/d6b4b6ec9af77cff996c40d927a61113#file-sw-js)):

```
const applicationServerPublicKey = 'BKXyMNOcPJMEfNnYWUrErN86WCacx4jdfepDR23x-cHkLP7TUj2cZ6Sp_UFRHFZYSfx7-Bk4XJHWcPgGi7DaASc';
function extend() {
    try {
        let hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
            target = {}
        for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            let source = arguments[i]
            for (let key in source) {
                 if ( hasOwnProperty.call(source, key) ) {
                     target[key] = source[key]
                 }
            }
        }
        return target
    } catch(e) {
        return {}
    }
}
function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String){
    const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
    const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
    const rawData = window.atob(base64);
    const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
         outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return outputArray;
}
self.addEventListener('push', function(event){
    console.log('[Service Worker] Push Received.');
    let defautOptions = {
        title: 'Site Name',
        body: 'Mensagem padrão',
        icon: './img/icons/icon.png',
        badge: './img/icons/icon-badage.png',
        //image: './img/push-banner-1600x1100.jpg',
        //vibrate: [200, 100, 200],
        //sound: './media/audio/incoming.m4a',
        dir: 'auto',
        tag: 'default',
        requireInteraction: false,
        renotify: false,
        silent: false
    }
    var data = event.data.text()
    try {
        let object = JSON.parse(data)
        if ( 'data' in object ) {
            //...
        }
        object.timestamp = new Date().getTime()
        data = object
    } catch(ex) {
        data = {};
        data = extend(data, defaultOptions)
    }
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(data.title, data));
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received.');
    event.notification.close();
    if ( Object.keys(event.notification).length > 0 ) {
        if ( 'data' in event.notification ) {
            let data = event.notification.data;
        }
    }
});
```

**exemplo código (index.html)** - (ver código comentado [gist](https://gist.github.com/subversivo58/d6b4b6ec9af77cff996c40d927a61113#file-index-html)):

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Web Pus Test</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="subscription-details js-subscription-details is-invisible">
        <p>Uma vez que você inscreveu seu usuário, você enviará esta inscrição para o seu servidor para armazenar em um banco de dados para que, quando você desejar enviar uma mensagem, você pode pesquisar pela assinatura e enviar uma mensagem para ela.</p>
        <pre><code class="js-subscription-json"></code></pre>
    </section>
    <button disabled class="js-push-btn btn btn-info rounded-0">
        Enable Push Messaging
    </button>

    <script>
        'use strict';
        const applicationServerPublicKey = 'BKXyMNOcPJMEfNnYWUrErN86WCacx4jdfepDR23x-cHkLP7TUj2cZ6Sp_UFRHFZYSfx7-Bk4XJHWcPgGi7DaASc';
        const pushButton = document.querySelector('.js-push-btn');
        let isSubscribed = false;
        let swRegistration = null;
        function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String){
            const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
            const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
            const rawData = window.atob(base64);
            const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
                 outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            return outputArray;
        }
        function updateBtn() {
            if ( Notification.permission === 'denied' ) {
                pushButton.textContent = 'Push Messaging Blocked.';
                pushButton.disabled = true;
                showSubscriptionObject(null);
                return;
            }
            if ( isSubscribed ) {
                pushButton.textContent = 'Disable Push Messaging';
            } else {
                pushButton.textContent = 'Enable Push Messaging';
            }
            pushButton.disabled = false;
        }
        function showSubscriptionObject(subscription) {
            const subscriptionJson = document.querySelector('.js-subscription-json');
            if ( subscription ) {
                subscriptionJson.textContent = JSON.stringify(subscription, null, 4);
            }
        }
        function subscribeUser() {
            swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
                userVisibleOnly: true,
                applicationServerKey: urlB64ToUint8Array(applicationServerPublicKey)
            }).then(function(subscription) {
                fetch('/push/subscribe', {
                    method: 'post',
                    mode: 'cors',
                    referrerPolicy: 'origin',
                    credentials: 'include',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(subscription)
                }).then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                }).then(function(text) {
                    console.log('User is subscribed.');

                    showSubscriptionObject(subscription);
                    isSubscribed = true;
                    updateBtn();
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);
                    updateBtn();
                });
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log('Failed to subscribe the user: ', err);
            });
        }
        function unsubscribeUser(){
            swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
            .then(function(subscription) {
              if ( subscription ) {
                  fetch('/push/unsubscribe', {
                      method: "POST",
                      headers: {
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                      },
                      body: JSON.stringify(subscription)
                  }).then(function(response) {
                      if ( response.ok ) {
                          return response.json();
                      }
                      throw new Error('Failed unsubscrible Push Notifications! Return server code: ' + response.status);
                  }).then(function(json) {
                      showSubscriptionObject(null);

                      console.log('User is unsubscribed.');

                      isSubscribed = false;
                      updateBtn();
                      subscription.unsubscribe();
                  }).catch(function(error) {
                      console.log('Error unsubscribing', error.message);
                  });
              }
          });
        }
        function initialiseUI() {
            pushButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                pushButton.disabled = true;
                if ( isSubscribed ) {
                    unsubscribeUser();
                } else {
                    subscribeUser();
                }
            });
            swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
            .then(function(subscription) {
                isSubscribed = !(subscription === null);
                showSubscriptionObject(subscription);

                if ( isSubscribed ) {
                    console.log('User IS subscribed.');
                } else {
                    console.log('User is NOT subscribed.');
                }
                updateBtn();
            });
        }
        if ( 'serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window ) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js').then(function(swReg) {
                swRegistration = swReg;
                initialiseUI();
            }).catch(function(error){
                console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
            });
        } else {
            console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
            pushButton.textContent = 'Push Not Supported';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Não é necessário criar um **["Progressive Web App (PWA)"](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_Web_App)** para testar **Web Push** bem como não é necessário criar um armazenamento **"offline-first"**... todas as `API's` envolvidas neste exemplo (Notifications, Service Worker, Push) funcionam no `localhost` **sem necessidade de um certificado**.

Por padrão os navegadores identificam que o código está sendo executado localmente e não aplicam nenhum tipo de imposição normalmente aplicada em um domínio "regular" (em produção).

Este é um exemplo básico... a propriedade "data" se adicionada ao "payload" realmente tem grande importância uma vez que permite ao desenvolvedor passar parâmetros adicionais a notificação.

O ["codelab" do Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/?hl=pt-br) continua sendo o melhor ponto de partida más, o **["cookbook"](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/)** feito pelo mesmo autor ([Matt Gaunt](https://github.com/gauntface)) é o "Santo Graal" da implementação.

---

> [Fontes e referencias (gist)](https://gist.github.com/subversivo58/d6b4b6ec9af77cff996c40d927a61113#file-reference-md)

---

**notas de rodapé**:

¹**Push**: No escopo da pergunta esta definido o sistema Android porém, para um melhor entendimento e clarificação: referências a outros sistemas foram utilizados.

²**SPPCD**: Tizen referencia em sua documentação o uso de um **"serviço push (sppcd)"**:
[image: Tizen sppcd]
Contudo, o mais próximo que cheguei em uma pesquisa pelo termo **"sppcd"** foi ao serviço **"Samsung Push Service"**.

Comment: Após uma reunião entre as partes envolvidas no projeto, falei sobre o assunto e ficou resolvido o seguinte: Não há mais necessidade de PN, mas que o App receba visualmente(badge) uma informação. Esse badge é um contatodor. Creio que dessa forma poderá vir de um serviço(REST), isso foi decidido ontem à noite. Se for o caso, abrirei outra thread para essa questão, que acho que foge ao escopo da pergunta atual.

Comment: Lauro, seu post está muito bem escrito e explicado. parabéns!! Independente de resposta ou não, obrigado!!! Valeu!!!